# MVC datetime field has different appearance in chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I developed an MVC 4.0 app using VSTS 2012 and .Net 4.0. I've created a class with a date type property as below

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[DisplayName("Start Date")]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

And in view, I am populating this property as below

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-1">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate)
</div>
```

When I see that in IE, it displays it correctly and on clicking text box I can see date box but when I test that in Chrome, I see a weird 'up-down arrow' along with a down arrow for date drop down. 
I am using IE 10 and Chrome 29 on windows 7. 
Does anyone have any idea why this different behavior and how to resolve that?

In IE

[image: This is from IE]

In Chrome

[image: This is from Chrome]

Answer (score 1):

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate)` will render as `<input ... type="date" .../>` in HTML.

It is a [HTML 5 input type](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html) and it will display differently in diffrent browsers.

You can try [Jquery Date Picker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) for cross browser functionality.